# Where can I find out if a graphics card will work on the newest versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, graphics, dell, xps

I'm really a newbie at graphics cards and have NO clue anything about them. I want to surprise my dad for his birthday with a fairly nice graphics card as his old one doesn't work with new versions of Ubuntu. He cannot run Unity at all and he wishes to.
He has a Dell XPS 410 Desktop. I'm looking for a card that will run Ubuntu 13 and future versions. He doesn't play any games, he surfs the web constantly. I don't have a lot of money, 300$ is my limit for this card. I've looked through the hardware supported but as I'm not really good at an of this I have no idea what it means. Could someone just suggest a few good cards? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [Component catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/).  The component catalog contains devices from 242 manufacturers.

You could also check out the [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)

Comment: Items from the component catalog are guaranteed to work with Ubuntu 13.04 ? Awesome catalog, thank you for it :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad help.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it really doesn't matter anymore. I found that both nVidia and AMD have great proprietary drivers. Nvidia might have a bit better drivers I think.

So no worries about drivers.. just worry about which card fits your needs and budget best. :)

Comment: That's kind of what I want to know, which card will fit my needs & budget? But I am glad to know that the drivers will work well as I had not thought of that